# How to start different Desktop Environments?

Tags: desktop-environments

Suppose I have ubuntu desktop and installed xubuntu desktop and want to try it, how do I start it? Is it any different if I want to try lxde? I reverted my virtual box to when I dont have a GUI then tried startx but I got something like command not found or something (can't remember)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the login screen you can choose the environment at the bottom of the screen after you've typed/selected your user name

Comment: Hmm but I installed a server version and dont have a GUI yet.

Comment: If you install a metapackage like ubuntu-desktop you'll get all the needed GUI packages including gdm/kdm/xdm and you'll see a graphical login after reboot. Use "sudo service gdm" if you don't want to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Besides installing the DE and all the necessary xorg server and drier components, you need to install a login manager such as `gdm` or `xdm`, then switch to runlevel 5 to activate it.